# Redirect to output file in HDFS

Tags: c#, redirect, hadoop, hdfs

I want to be able to redirect from a user portal to the output file page in hdfs file system produced after running a hadoop map-reduce job.

I can currently redirect to the output file page with the following refpath

```
http://{slave}:{port}/browseDirectory.jsp?dir=%2Fuser%2F{$USERNAME}%2F{$OUTPUTFILENAME}&namenodeInfoPort=50070&nnaddr={MASTER}:{PORT}
```

But this can be accessed only locally. How can I access the same from a remote server?
I have tried looking at webHdfs api's but failed to figure out how to work with it.

Comment: Did you consider moving your output files to s3 or something and then link to that ?

Comment: No. I donot want to move files from on premise.My master is connected to a static Ip address.Is there a way to make them accessible from the machine itself? Thank you.

Comment: Start a web server on your master and move the file there.